# how to call 'calculate_flash_loan_fees' from my solana program

Tags: solana-program

I am writing a solana program to read the flash loan fee.
Here's calculate_flash_loan_fees function:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token-lending/program/src/state/reserve.rs#L689

can i call calculate_flash_loan_fees from my solana program? how to call it?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call that function once you have unpacked the reserve `let mut reserve = Reserve::unpack(&reserve_info.data.borrow())?;`

```
let (origination_fee, host_fee) = reserve
    .config
    .fees
    .calculate_flash_loan_fees(flash_loan_amount_decimal)?;
```

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/8d88fb6c88a1bd5d0b55a47690943a173d7dd86e/token-lending/program/src/processor.rs#L1579-L1582

Your program is called with ix data containing `returned_amount_required` which is the loaned amount plus the fees, so in general you wouldn't need to know the exact fee amount since you need to return that whole amount at the end anyway

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/8d88fb6c88a1bd5d0b55a47690943a173d7dd86e/token-lending/program/src/processor.rs#L1630